# bind UriMapper.Uri to a static resource in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding, uri

Is it possible to bind the uri in the code below to a static resource? I have the urls defined in a resource file and wanted to bind to that rather than hardcoding the values here.

```
<navcore:UriMapper x:Key="uriMapper" >
            <navcore:UriMapping Uri="Home" MappedUri="/Home.xaml" />
</navcore:UriMapper>
```

I tried to declare a static resource and bind to it like in the example below but it failed

```
<Application.Resources>

        <local:URLContainer x:Key="URLContainer" />

        <navcore:UriMapper x:Key="uriMapper" >
            <navcore:UriMapping Uri="Home" MappedUri="{Binding Source={StaticResource URLContainer}, Path=HomeUrl}" />
        </navcore:UriMapper>

</Application.Resources>
```

Error that i get when i enable CLR exceptions is:

> Object of type
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot
>   be converted to type 'System.Uri'.

I have made the resource file constructor public and set the access level to public too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MappedUri` is not a `Dependency Property`, thus it can't be set through DataBinding.